# Using audio data with ParseSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb-query, parse-server

I am working on an iOS app using ParseSwift (1.7.1) and I have a collection in a Mongo DB.

Here is how a document looks:

```
_id
:"07BOGA8bHG"
_p_unit
:"OtherCollection$mzWqPEDYRU"
SENTENCE
:"I love nature peace and freedom."
Order
:5
ownerID
:"lGutCBY52g"
AUDIO
:"07067b5589d1edd1d907e96c1daf6da1_VOICE.bin"
_created_at
:2020-03-13T11:42:17.483+00:00
_updated_at
:2020-03-13T11:42:19.336+00:00
```

Here is how the data type for this collection is currently declared in my iOS Swift app:

```
struct TheCollection: ParseObject,Identifiable,Equatable,Hashable {
    //: These are required for any Object.
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    // Local properties.
    var id:UUID {return UUID()}
    var SENTENCE: String?,
        Order: Int?,
        ownerID: String?,
        //AUDIO: String?, .... causes trouble!
        unit: Pointer<OtherCollection>?

    //: Custom initializer.
    init(sentence: String,
         order: Int, unit: Pointer<OtherCollection>) {
        self.SENTENCE = sentence
        self.Order = order
        self.unit = unit
    }


    static func ==(lhs: TheCollection,
                   rhs: TheCollection) -> Bool {
        return lhs.SENTENCE == rhs.SENTENCE /*&&
            lhs.AUDIO == rhs.AUDIO*/
    }


    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(SENTENCE)
        //hasher.combine(AUDIO)
    }
}
```

My question is about the AUDIO field. It points to some important chunk of audio data on the server.

What is the type I should use for AUDIO ?

I already know that if I use String (as commented out) I run into trouble. But I am not sure what to use instead.

Comment: I'd prefer to use File if this chunk can have a big size. Otherwise you can try Binary.

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. Well, in the app I am working on at the moment, the files are MP3 between 30KB and 300KB. They could also be M4A files in the same size range.

And more important when I tried to follow your suggestions, I get these error messages:

"Cannot find type 'File' in scope"
or
"Cannot find type 'Binary' in scope"

And beside I can also see these messages:
"Type 'DataType' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'" and
"Type 'DataType' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'".

Are these types the ones you really meant?

Or am I missing some details?

Comment: It looks Binary is not implemented in Swift SDK yet, but File is implemented. The type name is actually 'ParseFile'. You can refer to the test cases in order to learn how to work with hem: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/0ea2385520858b824582a336c50387fe28b04bab/Tests/ParseSwiftTests/ParseFileTests.swift

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. Yes this document was relevant and helped me to figure out what I needed, with a bit of time and some guessing and trials. Thanks !